# How to summarize multiple logical columns into one extra column?

Tags: r

I have been searching around but couldn't find similar questions...

I have something similar like this:

```
data<-data.frame(RESULT1=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),RESULT2=c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),RESULT3=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE))
```

and I wanted to have a summary column based on multiple logical columns so that it turned out to be:

```
  RESULT1 RESULT2 RESULT3  COMMENTS
1    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE  RESULT1
2    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE  RESULT1,RESULT2
3   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE  RESULT2,RESULT3
4   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE  RESULT3
```

I wrote a very clumsy function a while back which does work, but there must be much better way to write this...

```
data$COMMENTS<-""
for(res in c("RESULT1","RESULT2","RESULT3")){
data$COMMENTS[eval(parse(text=paste("data$",res,sep="")))==TRUE] <- sapply(data$COMMENTS[eval(parse(text=paste("data$",res,sep="")))==TRUE],function(x){if(x==""){return(paste(x,res,sep=""))}else{return(paste(x,res,sep=","))}})}
```

Any suggestions is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
data["comments"] <- 
  apply(data, 1, function(x) paste0(names(data)[x], collapse=","))
```

Produces:

```
  RESULT1 RESULT2 RESULT3        comments
1    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE         RESULT1
2    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE RESULT1,RESULT2
3   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE RESULT2,RESULT3
4   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE         RESULT3
```

Comment: Nice!! Thanks! I tried apply by writing : apply(data,1,function(x){return(ifelse(x==TRUE,names(x)[x==TRUE],""))}),collapse=","), which was not working...didn't know I could write it this way. Thanks!!! :)

Comment: The problem with this `if( x==TRUE )` is that `x` is a vector of length 3 so it cannot possibly "just equal" TRUE. What happens in practice is that only the first item in the resulting vector is tested.

Comment: Thanks! :) This is also great example helping me to understand how apply works much better.